# What is the correct way to handle errors between classes?

Tags: python

I am using callbacks, it's rather clunky so I wanted to learn more about the methods of handling errors between classes, and what the best way to propagate the error to the main class.

If we have the following class layout:

1. Main class (manages user input)
2. Worker class (Object with some functions, eg. fetch data from mailbox)
3. Helper class (Object with helper functions)

Since I am using callbacks, when I create a Worker object, I give it a callback, which then trickle's down to the Helper class. So when the Helper class generates some known error, it moves "up" to the main class, and that error is notified to the user.

Comment: Are you using an asynchronous framework like Twisted?

Comment: No, it's all code I've written.

Comment: Is there a reason for not raising and catching custom exceptions?

Comment: If I raise and catch an exception on the lowest class, that error needs to be passed up to the main class so it can notify a user. The lowest class has no way of doing such a thing.

Comment: @user791953 : unhandled exceptions do propagates up the call stack by themselves. See my full answer below...

Comment: Raising exceptions using callbacks can cause some issues if you're running asynchronous code.  If you're not running async code, why are you bothering with the complexity of callbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make it much more complicated than it needs to be. Exceptions pop up the call stack until they are handled. That's exactly the point of having exceptions instead of error codes : you don't have to pass them all along the stack, they do so by themselves.

So, just *raise* exceptions from the lower level code and catch them at the upper level - or more exactly: catch them where you can handle them, and add a top-level catch-all handler for unhandled exceptions that logs the error (the builtin logging module is your friend), try to recover if possible, else display a user-friendly error message and try to terminate the application as cleanly as possible.

```
import logging
logger = logging.get_logger("myapp")

def something_deeper():
   raise SomeException("yadda")

def execute_some_code(*args)
   do_something()
   something_deeper()
   this_wont_happen()

def main(*args):
    configure_logging()
    try:
       execute_some_code(*args)
    except SomeRecovarableException as e:
       warn_user(e)
       try_to_recover_from(e)
    except SomeUnrecovarableException as e:
       logger.exception("oops, crashing")
       try_to_exit_cleanly_if_possible()
    finally:
       do_some_cleanup()            

if __name__ = "__main__":
     import sys
     main(*sys.argv())
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll study your example and see what can be done.